# makes the high cost of convenience "seem" - should it be "seems"

Tags: complementation, bare-infinitives, causative-make

I had read a sentence in a magazine:

> Staying connected is what makes the high cost of convenience—an average
>   of $3,300 a year for the Moore's plan—**seem** well worth it to them.

Should "seem" be replace by "seems"? Since "Staying connected" is a single noun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Seem* is not a finite verb, inflected for number, person and tense, but a non-finite form: the unmarked infinitive which is required in clauses complementing causative *MAKE*.

We say

> The Devil **made** me **do**<sup>INFINITIVE</sup> it.

and

> A good teacher knows how to **make** her students **be**<sup>INFINITIVE</sup> attentive.

Likewise, your author says (I've edited some to simplify and make the structure clearer, but it doesn't affect the point at issue):

> Staying connected **makes** the cost **seem**<sup>INFINITIVE</sup> worth it.

Answer (score 2):

If you cut out the extra information, the sentence reads a lot more clearly.

> Staying connected is what makes the cost seem well worth it to them.

Breaking it down a bit further into components:

> X is the thing that makes Y true for Z.

In this case "X" is "staying connected", Y is "the cost seeming to be worth it", and Z is "them" (whoever that happens to be in the magazine article). So as you can see, *staying connected* and *seem* aren't a subject/verb pair. It's almost a cause and effect statement; you're basically saying "because X exists, Y happens (in relation to Z)."